# Dynamic spinner creation not working as intended

Tags: java, android, xml

Im currently facing a problem while creating an app.

The user on NewGameActivity.java is prompted to choose the number of players playing the game (1-4). Once chosen they press "start game", they are redirected to the next page.

The next page is Hole1Activity.java, Where the user has to register the score through spinners. The app should generate the amount of spinners equivallent to the number of players selected in NewGameActivity.java, but it is not. This is the problem.

The following code is the code for both java activities and the XML layout for Holeactivity.java:

**NewGameActivity Code**:

```
package com.ID21027690;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class NewGameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newgame);

        // Initializes a "spinner" (drop-down menu)
        Spinner spinnerNumberOfPlayers = findViewById(R.id.spinnerNumberOfPlayers);

        // Creates an array for the spinner
        String[] numberOfPlayersArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

        // Array to XML layout adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numberOfPlayersArray);

        // Specifies the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Applies the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerNumberOfPlayers.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Sets up the button and its click listener
        Button buttonStartGame = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartGame);
        buttonStartGame.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Gets number of players from the spinner
            String selectedNumberOfPlayers = (String) spinnerNumberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem();

            // Starts Hole1 and tells how many players are playing the game
            Intent passnumbers = new Intent(this, Hole1Activity.class);
            passnumbers.putExtra("NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS", Integer.parseInt(selectedNumberOfPlayers));
            startActivity(passnumbers);

            //Sends user to first hole page
            Intent redirecttohole = new Intent(NewGameActivity.this, Hole1Activity.class);
            startActivity(redirecttohole);
        });
        }
}
```

**Hole1Activity.java**:

```
package com.ID21027690;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;

public class Hole1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hole1);

        // Get the LinearLayout where Spinners will be added
        LinearLayout playersLayout = findViewById(R.id.playersLayout);

        // Retrieve the number of players from the Intent
        int numberOfPlayers = getIntent().getIntExtra("NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS", 1);

        // Creates amount of spinners equal to the number of players
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            Spinner shotCount = new Spinner(this);
            shotCount.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId()); // Use ViewCompat for backward compatibility
            playersLayout.addView(shotCount);

            // Define the array directly in Java for the scores (1 to 17)
            String[] scoresArray = new String[17];
            for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
                scoresArray[j] = String.valueOf(j + 1);
            }

            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scoresArray);

            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            shotCount.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        // Sets up the button and its click listener
        Button buttonSubmitScores = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmitScores);
        buttonSubmitScores.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // TODO: Handle the Submit Scores and activity redirection on button click
        });
    }
}
```

**current layout for activity_hole1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#1fde52"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hole_page"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <!-- spinner creation -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playersLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
        <!-- spinners should be added here depending on the number of players -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmitScores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#159939"
        android:text="@string/submit_scores"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried giving the code small tweaks but the problem persists.

I also ran the app while checking Logcat, no errors are shown

What am I missing here?

Comment: And what is the result? I only see that you do not defined any LayoutParams for all new Spinners, but all the rest SEEMS fine or at least logical correct.

Comment: @emandt The result is the hole activity opening up and only having one spinner no matter whether I choose 1, 2, 3 or 4 players. I tried changing the for lop in Hole1Activity.java to add the parameters to the spinners (trying to keep it dynamic) but it didn't fix the problem.

any ideas on something I haven't checked or an alternative to this?

Comment: Are you sure the Hole's "for...numberOfPlayers" is looping N-times as much you expect? If yes: try changing the simple "addView(spinner)" to "addView(spinner, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT))"